# Compile time code expansion using template parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr, expansion

I fully expect this to not be a feature, but figured I may as well ask; is it possible to expand code at compile time using template parameters?

For example:

```
template <size I>
void foo()
{
    ...double... vec;
}
```

Where the ... Is replaced by `std::vector< >`, `I` times.

So `foo<2>()` would compile to:

```
void foo()
{
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec;
}
```

I can't even imagine what the syntax for this would be, so I'm not hopeful.

It would be useful for something like an N dimensional binning class, which could also be implemented through recursion, but not so neatly imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You can do it with class templates and specializations, like this:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct MultiDim {
    using underlying = typename MultiDim<N-1>::type;
    using type = std::vector<underlying>;
};
template<>
struct MultiDim<1> {
    using type = std::vector<double>;
};
template<std::size_t N>
using multi_dimensional = typename MultiDim<N>::type;
```

Hence, `multi_dimensional<1>` is `vector<double>`, and `multi_dimensional<N>` where `N>1` is `vector<multi_dimensional<N-1>>`.

Comment: A little doubt: what happens calling `MultiDim<0>`? (in case of `foo<0>()`)?

Comment: That depends on what you like. If you regard 0-dim as a scalar, you can define a `MultiDim<0>` with `using type = double;` in it. If you think this is erroneous, you can add `static_assert(N>0, "some message");` in the template `MultiDim<T>`.

Comment: It seems to me that If `foo<0>()` is a valid call (I suppose with `double vec;`), the `static_assert()` solution is wrong, because give an error in a legit implementation, and only a `MultiDim<0>` specialization is the only valid solution. If `foo<0>()` isn't a valid call, both solutions (IMHO) are acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to expand code at compile time using template parameters?

Directly... I don't think so.

But I suppose you can implement a specific type traits as follows

```
template <typename T, std::size_t I>
struct bar
 { using type = std::vector<typename bar<T, I-1U>::type>; };

template <typename T>
struct bar<T, 0U>
 { using type = T; };
```

and use in `foo()` in this way

```
template <std::size_t I>
void foo ()
 {
   typename bar<double, I>::type  vec;
 }
```

If you want to be a little more generic, you can also pass `std::vector` as a template-template parameter; if you define `bar` as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class C, typename T, std::size_t I>
struct bar
 { using type = C<typename bar<C, T, I-1U>::type>; };

template <template <typename ...> class C, typename T>
struct bar<C, T, 0U>
 { using type = T; };
```

`foo()` become

```
template <std::size_t I>
void foo ()
 {
   typename bar<std::vector, double, I>::type  vec;
 }
```